# Access files on remote computer via VPN

Tags: vpn, cisco, mac-osx, remote-access, file-sharing

**Environment:**

We have Office Mac Pro. I have Mac Mini at my home. I can connect to Office VPN.

**Question,**

How can I access file in Shared folder from Mac Pro from home? I have tried smb:// and afp:// from Mac Mini to connect to Mac Pro local ip but it doesn't connect.

I am sure I am missing some steps here.

Answer (score 0):

This depends. I use OpenVPN for a setup like this with good results but any other VPN implementation should work along the same lines. Basically, the main thing is that:

- OpenVPN will connect servers and clients to a specific VPN subnet -
  say 192.168.11.0/24
- The VPN subnet has no routes to anything other
  than itself per default. So - if your smb shares are on 192.168.10.1
  for instance, you are probably just missing a route.
- In OpenVPN, you can push routes to other places to the clients so they can know about
  subnets beyond the OpenVPN subnet.

In my OpenVPN config, I have these lines:

```
push "route 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0"
route 192.168.40.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.11.1
```

They basically just mean that the clients are given a route to a subnet on the server side (the 192.168.10.0 net) and that on the server side, we should add a route to the 192.168.40.0 net that goes through the VPN gateway (192.168.11.1). Most of the time, you will likely have to specify routes both ways to get everything in shape.

You can also do per-client configuration in the OpenVPN `ccd` config directory. Check out the documentation on `iroute` for more on this if you need routes to come up or down with client connections.

OpenVPN (if this is what you are using) has extensive examples